# Webscraping: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

I am new at this, but trying to scrape data from the website that requires a log in. Getting an error trying to open it. It appear that the problems is in cookies, that they are not being properly stored?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
import urllib

username = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'
values = {'email': username, 'password': password}

session = requests.session()

login_url = 'https://login.aripaev.ee/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fOAuth%2fAuthorize%3fclient_id%3dinfopank%26redirect_uri%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Finfopank.ee%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FreturnUrl%253D%25252F%2526returnAsRedirect%253DFalse%26state%3dLjNuwARtELJnVPcF8ka2Jg%26scope%3d%252FUserDataService%252Fjson%252FProfile%2520%252FUserDataService%252Fjson%252FPermissions%2520%252FUserDataService%252Fjson%252FOrders%2520%252FUserDataService%252Fv2%252Fjson%252FProfile%2520%252FUserDataService%252Fv2%252Fjson%252FPermissions%2520%252FUserDataService%252Fv2%252Fjson%252FOrders%26response_type%3dcode&client_id=infopank&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Finfopank.ee%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FreturnUrl%3D%252F%26returnAsRedirect%3DFalse&state=LjNuwARtELJnVPcF8ka2Jg&scope=%2FUserDataService%2Fjson%2FProfile%20%2FUserDataService%2Fjson%2FPermissions%20%2FUserDataService%2Fjson%2FOrders%20%2FUserDataService%2Fv2%2Fjson%2FProfile%20%2FUserDataService%2Fv2%2Fjson%2FPermissions%20%2FUserDataService%2Fv2%2Fjson%2FOrders&response_type=code'
url = 'https://infopank.ee/ettevote/1/'

result = session.get(login_url)
result = session.post(login_url, data = values, headers = dict(referer=login_url))

cookieProcessor = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(cookieProcessor)

page = urlopen(url)
```

Error message:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
```

Any suggestions are welcome - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `urllib.request` with `requests`. If you are going to use `requests`, it will just work fine.

Remove these lines from your program:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
import urllib

cookieProcessor = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(cookieProcessor)

page = urlopen(url)
```

This code has the issue that it doesn't have the cookies that were in the `requests.session` and also that the call to `urlopen` uses the default opener which has no cookie support at all. Rather `opener.open` should have been used.

Replace this with:

```
page = session.get(url)
```

Then the `requests.session` keeps track of the cookies for you.

Comment: Thanks, Dan! It seems like I was trying too many solutions in desperation, but this worked.